# How to turn on tooltips in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How can I turn on tooltips for functions ? I mean if I want to call a function I have to insert proper parameters into that function. Normally Visual Studio shows a tooltip which shows hints about that function(parameters,descriptions etc). However somehow this tooltip doesn't show. How can I turn it on ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `Ctrl+Shift+Space`?

Comment: I think it is just Ctrl+Space. Also, Ctrl+. will open the tooltip thing when the cursor is on some text with a little red box (such as when you change a variable name or type a class name outside the current namespaces).

Comment: Ctrl+Space opens the IntelliSense dropdown list, but pressing Ctrl+Shift+Space inside the brackets of the method call gets the tooltip.

Comment: Have you checked Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense to see if your settings there are correct? My "Selection In Completion List" characters look like this: {}[]().,:;+-*/%&|^!~=<>?@#'"\

Comment: I have the same characters but not tooltip :D

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
Tried all the button combinations:

```
Ctrl+Space
Ctrl+ +
Ctrl+Shift+Space
```

and checked settings **Tools > Options > Text Editor**
But nothing helped me.
Problem was solved just by restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest VS software:

Only thing that works for me is "Hold Alt and press Enter for popup". No need to click the popup marker on the far left anymore..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my side. Here it was related to the fact that I had two screens with different solutions (e.g. 100% and 125%).

Another strange symptom was that some editors (Source Control Explorer, History) were only fully displayed after they had been refreshed (e.g. by resizing).